# Upgraded to Xcode 6.3.1 and now Alamofire has several compiler errors, and there are compiler errors not associated with a file

Tags: ios, swift, linker-errors, alamofire, xcode6.3

Here are the issues with Alamofire

Compiler Errors:

[image: I am getting these compiler errors]

Warnings:

[image: I am getting these warnings]

Here are the Errors with the rest of the app:

[image: Errors with rest of the app]

Here is what I have tried:

I updated my podfile and pods.  I have another library called SwiftyJson and it had 14 compiler errors then I updated the pod and that fixed it.  However Alamofire still has the issue.  I saw that it had been updated for swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3 however it doesn't seem to be working.  I also went to Edit->Convert->To Latest Swift Syntax, and that did not help.

Here is the podfile:

[image: Podfile]

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: I was able to fix the general app errors by deleting everything cocoa pods from the app then running pod setup, pod install.  However the Alamofire errors are still there.

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed the issue:

I removed `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'` (after I posted the question but before I tried this I changed the Alamofire podfile line from `pod 'Alamofire', '>= 1.2'` to `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'` that did not fix the issue but I kept it because that is what is on the Alamofire Github page) changed from the podfile then I ran `pod update` in the terminal.  Then I went back to the podfile and added `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'` then I ran `pod update` suddenly everything worked.